# How to check in python that at least one of the default parameters of the function specified

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

What is the best practice in python to check if at least one of the default parameters of the function is specified?

Let's suppose we have some function:

```
def some_function(arg_a=None, arg_b=None, arg_c=False)
```

with some default parameters. In my case, I need to check if either `arg_a` or `arg_b` is specified. So I thought of implementing something like this:

```
def some_function(arg_a=None, arg_b=None, arg_c=False):
    ...
    if arg_a is not None:
        ...
    elif arg_b is not None:
        ...
    else:
        raise ValueError('Expected either arg_a or arg_b args')
    ...
    ...
```

So, what is more pythonic way to implement such kind of functionality?

Comment: Do the arguments have to be set up that way? In order to force the user to use one or the other I might make the function definition `some_function(arg, using_a)` - that way there's no option to not specify either one or the other

Comment: agreed that IN GENERAL this is a bad pattern. You shouldn't try to overload functions in this way. If you're convinced this is the best for your use case, there are lots of great answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `all` to check if they all equal `None` and raise the `ValueError`:

```
if all(v is None for v in {arg_a, arg_b}):
    raise ValueError('Expected either arg_a or arg_b args')
```

this gets rid of those `if-elif` clauses and groups all checks in the same place:

```
f(arg_a=0) # ok    
f(arg_b=0) # ok
f()        # Value Error
```

Alternatively, with `any()`:

```
if not any(v is not None for v in {arg_a, arg_b}):
    raise ValueError('Expected either arg_a or arg_b args')
```

but this is definitely more obfuscated.

In the end, it really depends on what the interpretation of pythonic actually is.

Comment: Ok, but after your code I have to put if-elif once more, because I need to initialize some data depends on arg_a or arg_b

Answer (score 6):

Depends on what you expect as values for `arg_a` and `arg_b`, but this is generally sufficient.

```
if not arg_a and not arg_b:
    raise ValueError(...)
```

Assumes that `arg_a` and `arg_b` are not both booleans and cannot have zeros, empty strings/lists/tuples, etc. as parameters.

Depending on your needs, you can be more precise if you need to distinguish between None and 'falsies' such as False, 0, "", [], {}, (), etc.:

```
if arg_a is None and arg_b is None:
    raise ValueError(...)
```

Comment: This will fail if either arg_a or arg_b is the empty string, the empty list, or another 'falsey' value, not just if they aren't specified.

Comment: `arg_a == arg_b == None:` or `arg_a is arg_b is None:`

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using `kwargs` if you have quite a number of such named arguments with *mismatching* default values:

```
def some_function(**kwargs):
    reqd = ['arg_a', 'arg_b']
    if not all(i in kwargs for i in reqd):
        raise ValueError('Expected either {} args'.format(' or '.join(reqd)))

    arg_a = kwargs.get('args_a')
    arg_b = kwargs.get('args_b')
    arg_c = kwargs.get('args_c', False)
```

Comment: Halfway doing a similar post when I saw yours.  However I use a `set` of valid arguments and subtract that from the set of keys in kwargs to check for incorrect arguments.

Comment: @cdarke That's a good one. Would look cleaner, but creating another set from the kwargs is something to consider

Comment: In Py3 you can use set operations on view objects returned from  `dict.keys()`, or in Py2 use `dict.viewkeys()`

Answer (score 0):

> To check if at least one of the default parameters of the function
>   specified

The solution using `locals`, `dict.values` and `any` functions:

```
def some_function(arg_a=None, arg_b=None, arg_c=False):
    args = locals()
    if (any(args.values()) == True):
        print('Ok')
    else:
        raise ValueError('At least one default param should be passed!')

some_function(False, 1)            # Ok
some_function('text', False, None) # Ok
some_function(0, False, None)      # Error
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Answer (score 0):

Since you're proposing such a pattern, there's possibly some unifying meaning to `arg_a`, `arg_b` and `arg_c`. If that's so, you could ...

```
from enum import Enum

class Group(Enum):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()
    C = auto()

def some_function(val: int, t: Group):
    if t == Group.A:
        # do stuff with val
    elif t == Group.B:
        # do other stuff with val
    elif t == Group.C:
        # do other stuff with val

some_function(1, Group.A)
```

Here the caller is forced to specify both a value, and what the value corresponds to. This is tbh a bit of a hack around the lack of proper enumeration support in python and I've no idea if it's pythonic. It will however be picked up by a type checker.